# Vundle Vim not installing plugins

Tags: vim, centos7, vundle

I am working with vundle vim on Centos 7 and am currently having issues where I cannot seem to install plugins that have worked on other pcs and I cannot seem to remember how to fix this issue. So I removed my .vim and .vimrc and then re git cloned the vundle git.

So when I start vim I receive:

```
Error detected while processing /home/abarkley/.vimrc:
line   24:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line   26:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
line   27:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'ekalinin/Dockerfile.vim'
line   28:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
line   29:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'elzr/vim-json'
line   30:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'vim-perl/vim-perl', { 'for': 'perl', 'do': 'make clean carp dancer highlight-all-pragmas moose test-more try-tiny' }
line   31:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'jparise/vim-graphql'
line   32:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'IN3D/vim-raml'
line   34:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
line   35:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'
line   37:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
line   39:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
```

If I open vundle and do :PluginInstall it returns a Not an editor command error.

Also does the .vimrc need to be chmod in anyway after # sudo mv Test.vimrc .vimrc

My .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4

let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
                            \ 'active_filetypes': ['python', 'javascript'],
                            \ 'passive_filetypes': [] }

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'ekalinin/Dockerfile.vim'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'elzr/vim-json'
Plugin 'vim-perl/vim-perl', { 'for': 'perl', 'do': 'make clean carp dancer highlight-all-pragmas moose test-more try-tiny' }
Plugin 'jparise/vim-graphql'
Plugin 'IN3D/vim-raml'

Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'

Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd Filetype gitcommit setlocal spell textwidth=72
```

Comment: You should include the contents of your .vimrc.

Comment: So sorry. I forgot that portion. Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'ekalinin/Dockerfile.vim'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'elzr/vim-json'
Plugin 'vim-perl/vim-perl', { 'for': 'perl', 'do': 'make clean carp dancer highlight-all-pragmas moose test-more try-tiny' }
Plugin 'jparise/vim-graphql'
Plugin 'IN3D/vim-raml'

Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'

Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'

call vundle#end()
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4

let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
                            \ 'active_filetypes': ['python', 'javascript'],
                            \ 'passive_filetypes': [] }

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']


filetype plugin indent on
autocmd Filetype gitcommit setlocal spell textwidth=72
```

(First call rtp, and the bundle functionality, and then set the variables for the plugins)